# Reallocate Swift Let variable

Tags: swift, swift2

Swift question with the goal of understanding the language better:

I understand the difference between a `var` and `let`

`var` are mutable

`let` are final

I'm assuming both of these are written to the stack. Once a variable is created the object class that it stores is set. Is it every possible to change this?

```
let myVar = String("Hello")
// myVar.dynamicType is String
myVar.delete

let myVar = Int(123)
myVar.dynamicType is Int
```

Is there a way to reallocate the memory for a variable? I want to use the same variable name to mean a different thing in a different section on the code.

Comment: Please abandon that idea! It's bad design in every language

Comment: This seems very fishy. At worst, use local scopes with `do { … }`, or use some kind of union type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers in Swift (both constant and mutable), as in most other static type-checked programming languages, have a **scope** (see the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))) that defines the extent of their validity. A scope could be the body of a function, a file, a module, or just the body of a `for` loop. In a language like Swift, you cannot reuse the same identifier for two different values or memory cells inside the same scope, but you can do it in two different scopes. So the answer to your question is: you cannot do it in the same scope, but you can do it in different scopes. Note, however that you are not using the *same* memory, just the same *name* associated to a different piece of memory (in case of `var`) or a different value (in case of `let`).

Actually you cannot `delete` neither the value associated to an identifier, neither the memory itself (as it seems that you think possible in your example). This is impossible in any language that has stack allocated entities, since the recovery from the stack is automatic at the end of the current block of code.